# Invalid according to Policy: Extra input fields

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3

I have the following code:

```
var RNS3 = exports.RNS3 = function () {
  function RNS3() {
    _classCallCheck(this, RNS3);
  }

  _createClass(RNS3, null, [{
    key: 'put',
    value: function put(file, options) {
      options = _extends({}, options, {
        key: (options.keyPrefix || '') + file.name,
        date: new Date(),
        contentType: file.type
      });

      var url = 'https://' + options.bucket + '.' + (options.awsUrl || AWS_DEFAULT_S3_HOST);
      var method = "POST";
      var policy = _S3Policy.S3Policy.generate(options);

      let request = _Request.Request.create(url, method, policy);
      Object.keys(options.metadata).forEach((k) => request.set(k, options.metadata[k]));
      return request.set("file", file).send().then(setBodyAsParsedXML);
      // return _Request.Request.create(url, method, policy).set("file", file).send().then(setBodyAsParsedXML);
    }
  }]);

  return RNS3;
}();
```

but get this error:

```
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Invalid according to Policy: Extra input fields: x-amz-meta-barcodeid</Message><RequestId>F0B9D95CF756F958</RequestId>
```

i am using this library: https://github.com/benjreinhart/react-native-aws3